# How to remove ^M from org-babel code block executing on Linux from Windows OS?

Tags: org-babel, microsoft-windows

My problem is that every line executing on the remote Linux machine seems to be including a trailing ^M (as is shown as ? in the file name `apa?` below).

Content of my .org document:

```
* Test
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /plink:pi@raspberry:/home/pi/test
touch apa
touch bepa && echo
ls -al
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: total 8
: drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi 4096 Nov 23 21:35 .
: drwxr-xr-x 10 pi pi 4096 Nov 23 20:07 ..
: -rw-r--r--  1 pi pi    0 Nov 23 21:35 apa?
: -rw-r--r--  1 pi pi    0 Nov 23 21:35 bepa
```

If I ssh to my Linux machine and type the file name using tab completion I see

```
pi@raspberry:~/test $ ls apa^M
```

Running plink directly from a cmd.exe does not add ^M to the filename:

```
c:\>plink.exe -l pi raspberry "cd test && touch cepa"
```

I have saved the org document with Unix line endings, but I get the same result.

My current workaround is to add the `&& echo` to eat the ^M, but I'd really like to find a better one...

I'm running Emacs 25.1 and org-mode v8.3.6 on Windows 10. My Linux machine is a raspberryPi running raspian jessie.

Comment: You can try to run the `delete-trailing-whitespace` command

Comment: Running `delete-trailing-whitespace` did not change my document, nor the resulting filename...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the explanation from [kini](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14017/kini) I have now created a satisfactory solution by adding a parameter to org-babel-sh-evaluate:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :file-coding utf-8-unix :dir /plink:pi@raspberry:/home/pi/test
touch apa
touch bepa
ls -al
#+END_SRC
```

using the following defadvice:

```
(defadvice org-babel-sh-evaluate (around set-shell activate)
  "Add header argument :file-coding that sets the buffer-file-coding-system."
  (let ((file-coding-param (cdr (assoc :file-coding params))))
    (if file-coding-param
        (let ((file-coding (intern file-coding-param))
        (default-file-coding (default-value 'buffer-file-coding-system)))
          (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system file-coding)
          ad-do-it
          (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system default-file-coding))
      ad-do-it)))
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that org-babel executes code blocks by dumping them to a temporary file and then loading the file into whatever interpreter is to be used for the designated language (in this case, a shell).  When you specify a remote `:dir` argument, the temporary file is placed on the remote host using TRAMP via `with-temp-file`.

Unfortunately it seems this file doesn't inherit the coding system of the org buffer (though I guess that wouldn't make sense anyway).  Nor is its coding system autodetected from the OS running on the remote host (which probably would make sense).

I don't know what the best way to solve this problem is, but it should suffice to set the global default coding system so that new buffers automatically follow unix EOL conventions:

```el
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

As an Emacs user on Windows, this might prove inconvenient for you in other situations, though.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. The suggestion of using `(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` is a much less obtrusive work-around. I tried making a macro to toggle that variable but since it "Automatically becomes buffer-local" I have not figured out how to get the current default-value...

Comment: @kini Great suggestion, thanks! Setting `buffer-file-coding-system` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does using the DOS `cr+lf` (`^M^J`) in an org file actually have a benefit? I guess you will only open it in Emacs anyway. (Other editors should be able to come to terms with unix `lf` (`^J`) line endings too.)

To just set the encoding for this one file, do

```
 M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system <ret> utf-8-unix <ret>
```

and if necessary remove any ^M with

```
 M-x replace-string <ret> C-q C-m <ret><ret>
```

then of course save the file.